# How is $\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} (Y_i^2 - \bar{Y}^2 ) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2$?

Tags: statistics

I'm reading a book on statistics and I'm stuck trying to make sense on this:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} (Y_i^2 - \bar{Y}^2 ) = \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2$$

For reference I'm checking how to make estimators using the method of moments for $\mu$ and $\sigma ^2$ of a normal distribution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Expand the square on the RHS, group the terms and remember what $\bar{Y}$ is.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $$\bar Y = \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^n Y_j$$
Thus, start with the left-hand side
$$\begin{split}
\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} \left(Y_i - \bar{Y} \right)^2 &= \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{i=1} \left(Y_i^2 - 2\bar YY_i+\bar Y^2\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{n} \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1} Y_i^2\right) - 2\bar Y\left(\frac 1 n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \right)+\bar Y^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n} \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1} Y_i^2\right) - 2\bar Y^2+\bar Y^2&\,\,\,\,\,&(1)\\
&=\frac{1}{n} \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1} Y_i^2\right) - \bar Y^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n} \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1} Y_i^2\right) - \frac{1}{n} \left(\sum^{n}_{i=1} \bar Y^2\right)
\end{split}$$
where in $(1)$ you use the definition of $\bar Y$.

Comment: review step (3) since there is an important typo (same numbers are subtracted so the result is zero)... it still needs the expansion of $(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)^2$ explaining what happens with the cross-products.

Comment: Ooops I was missing the bar. Thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: I think that $\bar{Y}^2\neq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{Y}_i^2$ if any assumptions is done (actually $\bar{Y}^2$ is a constant, so How there are $\bar{Y}_i^2$?), consider that $\bar{Y}^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2+2\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i Y_iY_j$ quite different at first view ... the last step maybe is misleading.. try to use the left side relation to reach the left part now.

Comment: I can´t make an edit because is too short... in the last summation you have an index that is not needed, is just $\bar{Y}^2$ inside the sum (and the equation is still named (3)).

Comment: Sorry that was another typo. I had copied and pasted a TeX formula that had a floating $i$ index in it. Fixed.